# Регулярное выражение в селекторе jquery

Tags: html, jquery, регулярные-выражения, классы, css-selectors

Есть скрипт, который кликает на div с определенным классом 1 раз в сутки:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        if(!$.cookie('showChat')){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var date = new Date();
                var minutes = 60 * 12;
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
                $.cookie('showChat', "true", { expires: date });
                jQuery(".hoverl_ca29").click()
            }, 10 * 1000);
        }    
    });
</script>
```

Класс "**.hoverl_ca29**"

Проблема в том, что "**ca29**" - постоянно меняется на рандомное значение.

Подскажите, как в строке "**jQuery(".hoverl_ca29").click()**" сделать регулярку так, чтобы скрипт срабатывал в не зависимости от рандомного значения в названии класса?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Приведите несколько примеров рандомных значений. У целевого дива это единственный класс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это единственный/первый класс у элемента, то `$([class^="hoverl_"])`, если где-то в середине то `$([class*="hoverl_")`

Comment: Да, класс с включением в названии "hoverl_" встречается только 1 раз в коде на всей странице.

Только немного не понял, как должна выглядеть строка кода польностью.

Comment: `jQuery('[class*="hoverl_"]').click()` видимо

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, отлично работает конструкция:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        if(!$.cookie('showChat')){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var date = new Date();
                var minutes = 60 * 12;
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
                $.cookie('showChat', "true", { expires: date });
                jQuery('[class*="hoverl_"]').click()
            }, 10 * 1000);
        }    
    });
</script>
```